# How to disable zooming completely in MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop, shortcut

When I wheel-scroll - actually touch-pad scrolling - MonoDevelop zooms the text. I have no idea why *zooming* has non-removable shortcut, but I can't disable this zoom.

In recent version they made it to be triggered with Option key, but it still annoying because I use Option key to navigate code. And if I touch the touchpad... This happens pretty frequently.

How can I disable this *zooming* completely? Any hacks are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think The Xmarin team made similar to Visual studio. So the function of Visual studio will contain in Mono Develop.

Comment: VS has an option to turn it off.